# App connecting to internet in emulator but not in real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, connectivity

```
**private boolean serverResponse() {
    int status=0;
    try {

        URI uri = new URI("http://www.google.com");     
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(uri);


        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        status=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();


        if(status==200)
            return true;

    } catch (Exception e1) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connecting to URI and status"+status , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    return false;
}**
```

Above code works fine in emulator. Not in Real device. It goes to catch block as URI is not connected.
(Internet connection in real device is up)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the Android.manifest you add permissions to access the internet. that is most likely th problem
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

i added permission in manifest file too.
@Illegal Argument, how can i print logcat in real device?

Comment: keep your device plugged in and you will see the logcat . Please post your logcat response

Comment: Found the issue. Internet Connectivity shd be runned  Asynchronously.

Comment: @kadatt Can you elaborate?